# Compilation error with Xcode 4.2

Tags: iphone, objective-c, compiler-construction, xcode4, location

ok, I think I am officially going nuts...trying to run this code on xcode 4.2 with iOS 5.0 simulator and getting all sorts of errors. In this app, all I am trying to do is to run the core location API.

My location "controller" class:

.h:

```
#import Foundation/Foundation.h
#import CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h

@protocol locationReceiverDelegate
@required

- (void)locationUpdate:(CLLocation *)location;
- (void)locationError:(NSError *)error;

@end

@interface locationReceiver : NSObject <CLLocationManagerDelegate> {
    CLLocationManager *locMgr;
    id delegate;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) CLLocationManager *locMgr;
@property (nonatomic, assign) id delegate;

@end
```

.m:

```
#import "locationReceiver.h"

@implementation locationReceiver

@synthesize locMgr, delegate;


- (id)init
{
    self = [super init]; 
    if(self != nil) {
        self.locMgr = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
        self.locMgr.delegate = self;
    }

    return self; 
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation     *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation {
//  if([self.delegate conformsToProtocol:@protocol(locationReceiverDelegate)]) {
        [self.delegate locationUpdate:newLocation];
//      }
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
//  if([self.delegate conformsToProtocol:@protocol(locationReceiverDelegate)]) {
        [self.delegate locationError:error];
//  }
}


@end
```

I am getting an error in the .m file  that "@synthesize locMgr, delegate;" that "Existing ivar 'delegate' for assign property 'delegate' must be _unsafe_unretained"

Comment: This might not be your problem, but there's a type mismatch between the ivar and the property: the ivar is an `id`, but the property is an `id<locationReceiverDelegate>`.

Comment: Ask this on the Apple developer forums, Xcode 4.2 is unreleased and we cannot answer ARC questions here.

Answer (score 1):

You should not `assign` your delegate, rather do

```
 @property (nonatomic, retain) id delegate;
```

That should solve your problem.

Comment: Awesome, thanks - that did it indeed! Now I am not getting location at all though :(....

Comment: Well, did you remember to set yourself as delegate for the "controller" class from the class that initializes it?

Comment: Like `myController.delegate = self`

Comment: That's my controller file (locationReceiver.h):    #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>

@protocol locationReceiverDelegate 
@required

- (void)locationUpdate:(CLLocation *)location;
- (void)locationError:(NSError *)error;

@end

@interface locationReceiver : NSObject <CLLocationManagerDelegate> {
    CLLocationManager *locMgr;
 id delegate;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) CLLocationManager *locMgr;
@property (nonatomic, retain) id delegate;

@end

Comment: and .m file: #import "locationReceiver.h"

@implementation locationReceiver

@synthesize locMgr;
@synthesize delegate;


- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if(self != nil) {
  self.locMgr = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
  self.locMgr.delegate = self;
 }
    
    return self;
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation {

}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
}


@end

Comment: Sorry the UI here is ridiculous, but yes, I did do it...I am wondering if it has to do with the new xcode...:/

Comment: Locations weren't supported in the old simulator, maybe they are now, maybe not. Test on a device, and see what happens.

Comment: Regardless of the simulator, I am not getting any location on my console - getting this error message:Error: Error Domain=kCLErrorDomain Code=0 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (kCLErrorDomain error 0.)"

Comment: You probably have to ask this question in the iOS5 beta section of the apple developer forums.